# JOIN EACH not returning result

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying new feature in BQ - JOIN EACH. My table size are:

table1 - Row Count - 50,684,757 - 24 GB
table2 - Row Count - 305,900,337 - 111 GB

Here is what I am trying:
select SUM(table1.col1), SUM(table2.col1)
FROM table2 JOIN EACH table1 ON(..)
WHERE blah

In BQ Web Browser, I see that query runs and shows "Query complete". However no results are returned. There is no errors.

Is this a known issue?

Thanks,

Comment: Is the problem repeatable? Does it affect just this one query or all queries? Have you tried the command-line tool to see if it reproduces there as well?

Comment: Yes it is repeatable. It only affects this query. Rest of my queries are working fine.

Comment: Here is more info from command line: I have ... WHERE table1.col3 = 'a' AND table1.col4 BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2013-05-02'. When I use this, I get this error in command line: "BigQuery error in query operation: Field 'a' ambiguous or not found on both sides of the JOIN". When I run this ... WHERE table1.col4 BETWEEN '2013-05-01' AND '2013-05-02' it returned no result in less than 5 sec. If I do same in browser, it after 180 sec shows query complete with nothing returned. I know that there are result in the tables. Let me know what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: I have been told today by our analyst that none of their JOIN EACH call is working as of 8:30 am PST May 21st. The behavior is as described above showing "Query Complete" after 400 sec.

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Comment: Sorry for the delay! I'll move further discussion to the bug here: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in the BigQuery web UI on Firefox. Polling for long-running jobs was not working correctly, so any job that ran for more than 2 minutes exhibited the behavior described above.

We've fixed the bug, and the fix should roll out next week.